# Get across cross domain policy javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is my code

```
function load() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("change").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.example.com/xyz.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

The url for the `xhttp.open` is an example url to another domain with a txt file. What can I add to my code for this to work? Thanks.

Comment: you can't from the client side. that origin will have to give you access, use JSONP, or use a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is with [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Comment: Could you please post a code example here? I can't find any simple examples.

Comment: @WatchYoJet -- it's not a code problem.  You have to configure _the server_.  [Here](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) is a library that will help you with a Node server.  [Here](https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html) are instructions for Apache.